# Ain't got no negative concord

Tags: negation, negative-polarity-items, negative-concord

In Englishes which allow the usage of *ain't*, why do we put "no" afterwards?

> I ain't got no money.
>
> Your dad ain't got no nose.

Is it compulsory to use *no*  in order to make a proper structure with *ain't*?

Comment: Even without **ain't** it is common to hear something like "haven't you got no sense?" in the vernacular with a double negative. Another example is "I can’t go nowhere tonight." [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/3-things-you-must-know-about-double-negatives/) has something on this topic.

Comment: You can also hear 'ain't got any money', and 'ain't got the price of a cup of tea'.

Comment: What is ain't? Haven't heard it before.

Comment: If it's good enough for Nina Simone, then it's is good enough for me.

*I ain't got no home, ain't got no shoes
Ain't got no money, ain't got no class
Ain't got no skirts, ain't got no sweater
Ain't got no perfume, ain't got no bed
Ain't got no man
Ain't got no mother, ain't got no culture
Ain't got no friends, ain't got no schoolin'
Ain't got no love, ain't got no name
Ain't got no ticket, ain't got no token
Ain't got no god*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ain't* and "double negatives" (using *no*, *none*, *nowhere* etc with *not*) are both features of many non-standard varieties of English, all over the world.

Neither of them is used in any standard English; in the non-standard Englishes where they are used, they are often used together, but they can be used separately, as Michael Harvey says in a comment.

Comment: thank you, Colin Fine. Can you tell me why people would use the non-standard Englishes? For a words play?

Comment: No, @Abigbong: in their ordinary life. Nearly all languages exist in various varieties (sometimes called "dialects", but I prefer not to use that word because some people use it to mean just geographical varieties: those are not the only kind). Languages with national status often have a "standard" form, but many people speak different a different variety in their daily life. Most formal and official writing is in a standard version, but people will write their own variety in informal communications (like emails and texts), and in songs, for example.

Comment: I doubt any native speaker of English speaks so-called standard English all the time

Comment: @green_ideas Generally, the more educated you are, the more likely you are to use ain't and other features of dialectal speech knowingly.

Comment: ain't that the truth (?) hmmmm, no double negative there

Answer (score 1):

The habitual use of *ain't* no longer occurs in standard Englishes and its use in other varieties is stigmatised by some [misguided souls] as being indicative of lower social status and a lack of education. The history of *ain't* is interesting as the proscription against it appears, much like the proscription against the perceived phenomenon of so-called h-dropping, to have been the product of a middle class fad.

What may this have to do with the Original Poster's question one may wonder? Well, as can be seen from the first paragraph of the excerpt  from  *Syntactic Variation in English* further below, the occurrence of invariant *ain't* and the occurrence of negative concord (also known as "double negation") are  both features of all non-standard Englishes. In other words, in every non-standard variety of English both invariant *ain't* and negative concord are grammatical. So on this basis, the use of *ain't* automatically licences the use of further negative items within the clause, representing as it does, basic clausal negation. Notice, however, that this does not mean that the use of negative concord is *compulsory* in sentences with *ain't*—which, of course, it isn't in many varieties of English.

It's interesting to consider potential reasons *why* these two features are ubiquitous in non-standard Englishes. With negative concord, one could surmise that negative concord is prevalent cross-linguistically. Languages which don't exhibit negative concord are the exception, not the norm. However, this does not explain why negative concord is a feature of all Englishes apart from standard English. With invariant *ain't*, it could be argued that *ain't* is a product of both phonological processes and the general developmental arc in English of moving towards dropping inflection. However, again this does not explain why *ain't* should not exist in standard English but exist in all other varieties. Here, however, there is a simple and  cogent explanation: it is only in standard English that prescriptivists managed to artificially pervert the natural language in an attempt to socially distinguish its speakers from those considered to be of inferior social status.

Below is the relevant excerpt from  Bend Kortmann's 'Syntactic Variation in English: A Global Perspective' (in *The Handbook of English Linguistics*, Bas Aarts and April McMahon, eds. John Wiley & Sons. 2008. pp. 603—624)

### 4 Negation

> In the domain of negation the two negation features most widely known to
>   occur in all non-standard varieties are multiple negation (or negative concord) and invariant *ain’t*. But there are other negators, notably invariant *don’t*
>   and especially preverbal *never*, which are almost equally frequent. The other
>   two negation features presented below [N5—7] are used in considerably fewer nonstandard varieties:
>
> (N1)
>
> > Multiple negation / negative concord (e.g. *He won’t do no harm, I couldn’t
> >     say nothing about them, I’ve never been to market to buy no heifers*).
> >     The frequency with which multiple negation is used in individual nonstandard varieties may vary greatly. In white dialects of American
> >     English, for example, frequencies have been found to vary between 50
> >     and 80 per cent (Schneider 2000: 219). A striking pattern Anderwald
> >     (2002: 109–14 and unpublished work) has found in corpus-based studies
> >     of England, Scotland, and Wales is a south–north cline, with rough
> >     proportions of multiple negation usage of 40 to 45 per cent in the South
> >     of England, 30 per cent in the Midlands, and around 10 per cent in the
> >     North of England, Scotland and Wales. Interesting variation can also
> >     be found for syntactic and lexical constraints on multiple negation in
> >     different varieties (e.g. in African American Vernacular English multiple
> >     negation crosses clause boundaries, indefinite constituents of embedded
> >     clauses being marked negatively because the predicate of the superordinate clause is marked negatively; Schneider 2000: 219).
>
> (N2)
>
> > Ain’t. Invariant *ain’t* in present tense declaratives, questions, and tags
> >     represents a neutralization in the negative between *be* (e.g. *I ain’t going
> >     out tomorrow, They’re all in there ain’t they?*) and (auxiliary) *have* (e.g.
> >     *I ain’t had a look at them yet, Gotta be lucky at something, ain’t you love?*),
> >     as well as a neutralization of person distinctions of Standard English.
> >     In some varieties, especially pidgins and creoles, there is a tendency to
> >     extend the use of *ain’t* to full verb *have* (e.g. *Ain’t you trouble with your
> >     car?*). In fact, in African American Vernacular English *ain’t* is also used
> >     as a full verb negator equivalent to *don’t/doesn’t* and, especially, *didn’t*
> >     (e.g. *sumpin’ I ain’t know about, You ain’t expect to find her over here,
> >     did you?*; Schneider 2000: 214–15). In some pidgins and creoles, *ain’t*
> >     (or: *in/en/eh*) has even acquired the function of a general (i.e. tense-independent) preverbal negator (e.g. Trinidadian English *The girl eh lie*
> >     ‘The girl didn’t lie’) as further described in (N5).
> >
> > (p. 610)

---

Here is a relevant Wikipedia article on *ain't*, in which the section [*Proscription and stigma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t#Proscription_and_stigma) gives a brief overview of the social history of *ain't*.

Answer (score -1):

I think Mr Ashworth above has just answered your question. And yes, it is compulsory to add "no" to "ain't". This is called a double negative (as mentioned above as well). Don't use this phrase in polite company. It's substandard. Use it with your friends only.

Comment: It ain't compulsory to add "no". If you want to assert that it *is*, please provide supporting references.